# Unity: Google Play Games crashes on login

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to save a variable using google play games cloud save. However it crashes when it signs in. I've definitely enabled it on the developer console. I never had this problem before I added the cloud save feature and it was just doing achievements and scoreboards. Also, when I'm not connected to the internet, it doesn't crash and locally saving the data works fine. Can any one help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.SavedGame;
using System.Text;

public class playgamesscript : MonoBehaviour {

public static playgamesscript Instance { get; private set; }


const string SAVE_NAME = "Test";

bool isSaving;
textEdit textEditScript;
control controlScript;

bool isCloudDataLoaded;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Instance = this;

    textEditScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("UIControl").GetComponent<textEdit>();
    controlScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Control").GetComponent<control>();

    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(SAVE_NAME))
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(SAVE_NAME, "0");
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("IsFirstTime"))
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstTime", 1);

    LoadLocal();


    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().EnableSavedGames().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    if (control.signInAttempt == false)
    {
        SignIn();
    }
}

void SignIn()
{
    control.signInAttempt = true;
    Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => { LoadData();  });
}

#region Saved Games

string GameDataToString()
{
    return control.Highscore.ToString();
}

void StringToGameData(string cloudData, string localData)
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsFirstTime") == 1){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstTime", 0);
        if (int.Parse(cloudData) > int.Parse(localData)){
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(SAVE_NAME, cloudData);
        }
    }
    else if (int.Parse(localData) > int.Parse(cloudData))
    {
        control.Highscore = int.Parse(localData);
        AddScoreToLoeaderBoard(textEdit.leaderboardStat, control.Highscore);
        isCloudDataLoaded = true;
        SaveData();
        return;
    }
    control.Highscore = int.Parse(cloudData);
    isCloudDataLoaded = true;

}

void StringToGameData (string localData)
{
    control.Highscore = int.Parse(localData);
}

void LoadData()
{
    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        isSaving = false;
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithManualConflictResolution(SAVE_NAME, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, true, ResolveConflict, OnSavedGameOpened);
    }
    else {
        LoadLocal();
    }
}

private void LoadLocal()
{
    StringToGameData(PlayerPrefs.GetString(SAVE_NAME));
}

public void SaveData()
{
    if (!isCloudDataLoaded)
    {
        SaveLocal();
        return;
    }

    if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        isSaving = true;
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithManualConflictResolution(SAVE_NAME, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, true, ResolveConflict, OnSavedGameOpened);
    }
    else
    {
        SaveLocal();
    }
}

private void SaveLocal()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(SAVE_NAME, GameDataToString());
}

private void ResolveConflict(IConflictResolver resolver, ISavedGameMetadata original, byte[] originalData, ISavedGameMetadata unmerged, byte[] unmergedData)
{
    if (originalData == null)
    {
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(unmerged);
    } else if (unmergedData == null)
    {
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
    } else
    {
        string originalStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(originalData);
        string unmergedStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(unmergedData);

        int originalNum = int.Parse(originalStr);
        int unmergedNum = int.Parse(unmergedStr);

        if (originalNum > unmergedNum)
        {
            resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
            return;
        } else if (unmergedNum> originalNum)
        {
            resolver.ChooseMetadata(unmerged);
        }
        resolver.ChooseMetadata(original);
    }
}

private void OnSavedGameOpened(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        if (!isSaving)
        {
            LoadGame(game);
        } else
        {
            SaveGame(game);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isSaving)
        {
            LoadLocal();
        }else
        {
            SaveLocal();
        }
    }
}

private void LoadGame(ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.ReadBinaryData(game, OnSavedGameDataRead);
}

private void SaveGame(ISavedGameMetadata game)
{
    string stringToSave = GameDataToString();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(SAVE_NAME, stringToSave);

    byte[] dataToSave = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSave);

    SavedGameMetadataUpdate update = new SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder().Build();

    ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.CommitUpdate(game, update, dataToSave, OnSavedGameDataWritten);
}

private void OnSavedGameDataRead(SavedGameRequestStatus status, byte[] savedData)
{
    if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
    {
        string cloudDataString;
        if (savedData.Length == 0)
        {
            cloudDataString = "0";
        } else

        cloudDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(savedData);
        string localDataString = PlayerPrefs.GetString(SAVE_NAME);

        StringToGameData(cloudDataString, localDataString);
    }
}

private void OnSavedGameDataWritten(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game)
{

}

#endregion /Saved Games
```

///

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult.setResultCallback(com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback) on null object'
```

Comment: can you share the log of the exception?

Comment: I've put a small snippet of it in my question.

Comment: This error means there was an exception doing an asynchronous call in java.  Look in the log before this message to see what the exception is.

Comment: That error doesn't seems to be appearing in the log anymore and I can't find any exceptions in the log either. Although I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Comment: anyone has a solution?